# Scalable Pub/Sub engine for realtime

Tags: scalability, real-time, redis, publish-subscribe, sharding

I'm looking for a pub/sub engine, with the following requirements:

1. Very low latency < 0.5 sec
2. Scalable
3. Shardable (based on geo localisation)

I'd like to be able to have multiple pub/sub servers and be able to publish or subscribe to channels from any server, no matter on which server the channel is declared.

For example:

If **user A** is connected to server **SRV1** and **user B** connected to server **SRV2**, If **user B** subscribe to "*MyChannel*" and **user A** publish something on channel "*MyChannel*", **user B** will get the message even if he's not connected to the same server.

I don't know if Redis is able to do that. I didn't find anything about the subject.

Comment: Try activeMQ? http://activemq.apache.org/

Comment: This sounds like the infrastructure that we have built at [Pusher](http://pusher.com). We use WebSocket servers for low latency connection between clients and servers, AWS ELB for loadbalancing and a combination of queuing technologies. Point 3. hasn't been a big issue for us as yet but it's something we are looking into.

Comment: hi! Check out [Realtime.co][1]

[1]: http://framework.realtime.co/

Answer (score 4):

We've been using [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) and it's pub/sub features for while now and we're very happy with what we're seeing.

It's also worth looking at what's coming up in the next [version](http://www.zeromq.org/whitepapers:0mq-3-0-pubsub) (reducing network bandwidth by pushing subscription requests upstream)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you look at [Data Distribution Service for Real Time Systems (DDS)](http://portals.omg.org/dds/) standard. It's specifically designed to be a scalable pub/sub middleware both for real-time and non-real-time systems.

It has a few mature implementations all of which has it's own strength points, but generally the implementations are scalable and low latency.

These are the implementations I would suggest you look at (If you need them to work on a WAN environment, I guess the first two ones have great support for that):

- [RTI DDS](http://www.rti.com)
- [OpenSplice DDS](http://www.opensplice.org)
- [OpenDDS](http://www.opendds.org)
- [CoreDX DDS](http://www.twinoakscomputing.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for some sort of messaging. Try [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com), with [shovel](http://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html) or [federation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/federation.html) plugins

Answer (score 1):

[`nanomsg`](http://nanomsg.org/) is a successor to [`ZeroMQ`](http://zeromq.org/), written by the same author, and with many language-bindings.

It is written in C and uses zero-copy mechanisms. If you're looking for exceptional latency, and are willing to get your hands dirty ( which you should if you aim for something extreme ), I would recommend one of those two.

If you're looking for exceptional throughput, go with `Kafka`.

Note, none of those solutions implement geolocation out of the box, Redis 3.2 will have something : http://antirez.com/news/89

If you are looking for an easy, "good enough" solution, I'd go with `Redis` ( be sure to read [this blog post from aphyr](https://aphyr.com/posts/283-call-me-maybe-redis) first ).

Comment: Yes,**`nanomsg`** is a younger sister of smart & already widespread **`ZeroMQ`** masterpiece.For real insights,the more for soft-real-time ecosystem design, **worth reading Martin Sustrik's marvelous blog posts and publications** >>> http://250bpm.com on co-routines and other smart notes **+ Pieter Hintjens' book** in pdf : **"Code Connected, Vol.1"**.(Btw. 500 ms latency is a very non-real-time-ish criterion, an infrastructure is the issue,where a poor Layer3 transport service may invalidate meeting such limit. Both `ZeroMQ` and `nanomsg` have excellent latency-avoidance,shaving-off ns(!s))